# Insert HTML form data to mySQL via PHP (form array vary from amount of table rows)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a HTML form where users can checkmark up to 50 different questions. They have to checkmark minimum 1 and at the most all 50 questions.

After they submit the form I need to insert the data (`form_array`) to my mySQL table **questions**. The table contains of **50 questions** rows (see below **question table** ex.).

I know the `INSERT INTO 'questions' (question1, question2, question3, question4,....question50) VALUES (value1, value2, value3...)`, but my challenge is that since the amount of checked questions (values) can vary in the form, I do not know how to insert the `form_array` to my **questions** table.

*The **questions** are inserted as **true** or **false** in the `form_array` depending on if they are marked or unmarked in the html form.*

The **questions** table has a primary auto incremented ID and 2 foreign keys besides the 50 questions.

I welcome all suggestions/examples on how to insert an array with the above scenario?

**The *question* table will look like this:**

```
  `question1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `question2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `question3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `question4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `question5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `question6...etc etc...up to 50 questions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store the **answers** to the 50 questions, right?

First of all, your table structure should look something like this:

```
questions
---------
id: primary key, int(11), auto increments
question/title: varchar(255)

answers
-------
id: primary key, int(11), auto increments
question_id: int(11)
answer: tinyint(1)
```

This is the tricky part. To display the questions (I used mysqli as I don't know what you're using):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from questions");

while ($question = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print 'Question: ' . $question['title'];
    print '<input type="hidden" name="answers[]['question_id']" value="' . $question['id'] . '">';
    print '<input type="radio" name="answers[]['answer']" value="1"> Yes'; 
    print '<input type="radio" name="answers[]['answer']" value="0"> No';
}
```

Now when a user submits his answers:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $answers = $_POST['answers'];

    if(count($answers) > 1) {

        //Loop through all the answers
        foreach($answers as $answer) {
            $mysqli->query("INSERTO INTO answer ('question_id', 'answer') VALUES ('{$answer['question_id']}', '{$answer['answer']')"); //Insert the answers one by one
        }

    } else {
       print 'You need to submit at least one answer!'
    }

}
```

I haven't tested the code. This is still pretty basic, but it's exactly what you need, I think... :-).

Comment: thank you @jasonk, I am new to databases and are a little confused on how to setup the questions table or more specific, the question/title. As mentioned I have 50 questions, do I understand you correct if §you suggest that I write those 50 questions in the question/title row (one pr. row)? Could you be more specific with and ex. and include the ex. with question 1, question 2 etc?

Comment: Or do you @jasonk want me to INSERT my 50 questions in the questions table so the questions each get and unique id to use for queries - is that correct understood?

Comment: Yes, you insert your 50 questions in the table `questions`. Each question is one row, so each question has a unique ID and a title (for instance: How do monkeys run?).

Comment: Did my effort help you in any way or?

Comment: I have not tested your suggestion yet but I will. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not make the solution work because I need each answer to be connected to a user id (sorry, I should have mentioned this in my original question). 

Also with this solution (if I understand it correct), I will get a lot of rows filled (in the ANSWER table) every time a user submits the form (on row pr question). And with the current activity which is 30+ submits pr. day this is going to be a lot of row filled everyday.

@jasonk please enlighten/correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Connecting an answer to a user is simple, just add the column `user_id` to `answers` table. Having many rows isn't bad, I've seen databases with millions of rows. You could serialize an array (of the 50 questions) and store it in the `answers` table. In that case you have one row for each filled in question form. This is however a little bit more tricky.

Comment: Ok I got that part @jasonk- thank you. But a user can submit a form multiple times during a week, month, year. therefore I need to store each submitted user answer so that I can query which answers a user submitted during lets say yesterday.

Comment: That can be done by adding the `user_id` column, and also a  `created_at` (datetime) column in the `answers` table. Then you could query whatever you want. For example: `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE user_id = '1' AND created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK`.

Comment: Ok thank you @jasonk. I will look into your suggestions. I really appreciate your help/suggestions. I will update and let you know how it works out.

Comment: ..@jasonk any suggestion on how to solve this: I need all INSERTS made in one query to have same id, because a user can submit several forms within 5, 10, 30 or x min, meaning it is difficult to extract user answers based on a datetime column. I tried the following, but got a "You can't specify target table 'task_in' for update in FROM clause" error from query:
 `INSERT INTO `answer_in` (`answer_id_unique`, `question_list_id`, `customer_id`, `user_id`, created_at)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(`answer_id_unique`)+1 FROM `answer_in`), (SELECT id from `question_list` WHERE `id`='5'), '1', '1', NOW())`